# ANR android to calculate cpf digit if it is valid

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting ANR from play store in a method of calculating CPF and CNPJ digits, calculating valid CPF

```
fun isValidCPF(cpf: String?): Boolean {
            if (cpf == null || cpf.length != 11) return false
            if (cpf.trim { it <= ' ' } == "00000000000") {
                return false
            }
            val digit1 = calculateDigit(cpf.substring(0, 9), weightCPF)
            val digit2 = calculateDigit(cpf.substring(0, 9) + digit1, weightCPF)
            return cpf == cpf.substring(0, 9) + digit1.toString() + digit2.toString()
        }
```

```
private val weightCPF = intArrayOf(11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2)
```

```
private fun calculateDigit(str: String, weightCPF: IntArray): Int {
            var sum = 0
            var index = str.length - 1
            var digit: Int
            while (index >= 0) {
                try {
                    digit = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 1))
                    sum += digit * weightCPF[weightCPF.size - str.length + index]
                    index--
                } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
                    Timber.e(ex, "calculateDigit: %s", ex.message)
                }
            }
            sum = 11 - sum % 11
            return if (sum > 9) 0 else sum
        }
```

Does anyone know why i am getting this ANR? I can't reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

You get an infinite loop when any of the characters isn't a digit:

```
while (index >= 0) {
    try {
        digit = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 1))
        sum += digit * weightCPF[weightCPF.size - str.length + index]
        index--
    } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
        Timber.e(ex, "calculateDigit: %s", ex.message)
    }
}
```

If `parseInt` fails, it throws an exception and jumps to the catch block without ever decrementing `index`, so you just end up spinning on the same `index` value and its invalid character forever.

I don't know how you want to handle invalid characters, but if you just want to skip them, you could put the `index--` outside the try/catch so it always runs every loop. If it should immediately fail, you could do an early return or throw an exception.

---

You also have an issue in your validation in `isValidCPF`:

```
if (cpf.trim { it <= ' ' } == "00000000000") {
    return false
}
```

This implies that you're *expecting* the the function might be passed non-digit values - just to check the digits aren't all zeroes, you're trimming *some* invalid chars (only the ones preceding `!` in [this table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) though). But that trim only happens *for this check* - the rest of your code still uses the original string. So when you do this:

```
val digit1 = calculateDigit(cpf.substring(0, 9), weightCPF)
```

If that trim **was** necessary to check the digits before, isn't it necessary now? What if it has leading non-digit characters? You're just taking the first 9, whatever they happen to be (which is probably how you're ending up with the infinite loop situation).

I don't know exactly what you're doing, but you might want to use something like `val trimmed = cpf.trim { !it.isDigit() }` or `{ it !in ['0'..'9']`) }. Or maybe even something like `val filtered = cpf.filter { it.isDigit() }` to remove all non-digit chars, and then decide if you have enough to consider it valid and continue processing. Depends what you're doing of course! Just giving you some options.

Answer (score 0):

I presume "ANR" means "Application not responding" and CPF and CNPJ are some acronyms that no-one outside of Brazil has ever heard about and that we don't need to know about.

This ANR would happen if your `while` loop never terminates. This can only happen if there is an error. Luckily, you are logging the error, so check your logs to see what's gone wrong.